# virtual environment for tester to test my local changes?

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, devops

Currently here's our workflow. I push code, the CI/CD build it deployed to an environment, tester test it on there. But the problem is each build take 20 minutes, we can go back and forth if the developer makes mistake. How to avoid go back and forth? I'm think of without pushing or running the CI/CD, tester can check my local, that would be faster. But how to do it without interrupting local development, I've no clue.

Comment: You clearly can't test while doing development, because you wouldn't be able to build - the tester would be using the app, which would prevent it from being built. You're asking *How can I let someone drive my car while my mechanic keeps working on it?*.

Comment: @KenWhite I can because at least I'm running the app locally, I can setup teamviewer for him to check isn't it? but I don't know how does that don't interrupt my workflow locally

Comment: That's what I'm saying. If you're running it locally for testing, you can't build it at the same time. You can't drive your car while it's in the shop being worked on, and you can't run your app while it's being built.

Comment: you're being too strict, you need to see the pain here, each hotfix take 30 min, says the system has an error that need an urgent fix, one have to wait 30 min, if the push doesn't fix the issue, go back and forth we need hrs to fix one small issue. What's your suggestion?

Comment: No, I'm not being too strict, I'm facing reality. If the build takes 30 minutes, it takes 30 minutes, and you can't do anything until that build is complete. Time machines don't exist. The real problem you're facing is the fact that your build takes too long - you should be looking at ways to reduce the build time. I can't make any suggestions, because I have no information about your architecture or application other than that the build takes too long.

Comment: that's how things work in big company, but I want to improve the workflow, imagine I alone waste 30 min per day, what if our team has 10 devs that are struggling the same issue?

Comment: Ok. Whatever you way. You're obviously not willing to listen, so there's not much point in spending more time here discussing it with you. Good luck!